# Grab Updated rows of pandas column while looping through dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.8

I am trying the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'B'},
 'Col2': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'b', 4: 'c'},
 'Col3': {0: 42, 1: 28, 2: 56, 3: 62, 4: 48}})

ii = 1
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
    df.at[:, 'Col2'] = 'asd{}'.format(ii)
    ii += 1
```

But the print statement above doesn't reflect the change `df.at[:, 'Col2'] = 'asd'.format(ii)`. I need the print statements to reflect the change `df.at[:, 'Col2'] = 'asd'.format(ii)`

Edit: Since I am updating all rows of `df`, I was expecting the `idx and row` to grab new values from dataframe.

If this is not the right way to ***grab updated values*** from `df` through `idx and row`, then what is the correct approach. I need `idx and row` to reflect new values.

Expected output:

```
Col1     A
Col2     a
Col3    42
Name: 0, dtype: object
Col1     A
Col2     asd1
Col3    28
Name: 1, dtype: object
Col1     B
Col2     asd2
Col3    56

.....
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `df.at[:, 'Col2']` be `df.at[idx, 'Col2']`? `df.at[:, 'Col2']` assigning to whole df.

Comment: No if you do only idx it doesnt update the entire df

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: From the documentation: "You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect." https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Comment: What is the alternate solution? Any ideas as I need to modify the row value due to legacy code.

Comment: As @Ch3steR said, can you show the desired output? Based on your explanation, I cannot tell what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

From [`iterrows` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

> You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not
> guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the
> iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no
> effect.

As per your request for an alternative solution, here is one using [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
df['Col2'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'asd{}'.format(row.name), axis=1)
```

Other examples (also using [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)) that may be useful for your eventual goal: *(not clear what it is yet)*

```py
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].apply(lambda x: 'asd{}'.format(x))
df['Col2'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'asd{}'.format(row['Col3']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'B'},
                   'Col2': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'b', 4: 'c'},
                   'Col3': {0: 42, 1: 28, 2: 56, 3: 62, 4: 48}})

print(
    df.assign(idx=df.index)[['idx', 'Col2']]
        .apply(lambda x: x['Col2'] if x['idx'] == 0 else f"asd{x['idx']}", axis=1)
)
```

---

```
0       a
1    asd1
2    asd2
3    asd3
4    asd4
dtype: object
```